# WSOD for logged users after upgrading some module

Tags: 7, debugging, wsod

I have updated the following modules on my website:

ctools
context
devel
ds
libraries
metatag
pathologic
rel_to_abs
variable
webform

After the upgrade whenever I log in, I am not able to access any page (not just the administration area).
Anonymous users have no problems.
Downloding the whole website and installing it locally with the backup before the update, everything works fine. 
I have enabled debug logs and all possibile error reporting options, but I have no error or warning of any kind.
I have increased the memory limit, clean every cache and run the registry rebuild via php.
I have no ssh access to the host, so I cannot run any remote debugging.
Can someone point me out to a possibile solution?

Comment: There must be an error message somewhere - have you checked the server logs?

Comment: Could you try to update locally the modules one-by-one to identify which one is kicking?

Comment: I assure there is no error anywhere. I already asked the hosting provider to enable the deepest level of error report. I am waiting for their answer.

Comment: Locally everything works fine.

Comment: It's pretty much unheard of for Drupal to white screen without an error message being logged. If it works locally, but not on your hosted version, it simply has to be an issue with server config. Your web hosts would be the best people to help with that, as obviously we can't gain access to the server

Comment: I answered my own question. The problem was Devel 7.x-1.4.

Answer (score 0):

go into you database, set the status to 0 on the rows for each of the modules you mentioned. Reinstall each module one by one to find the problem module.

you could also try adding this to the top of index.php (remember to remove it later)

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);
```

Comment: This is the first thing I did, but the problem is that some of these module are required by many others (ctools, variables, libraries). Disable them would mean have to disable all the dependent ones.

Comment: I would start with the rel_to_abs and ds modules. And any that are the the dev version of the module.

Answer (score 0):

The problem ended up being Devel 7.x-1.4 dropped support for PHP 5.2.
A patch has been submitted to fix the issue and has been commited to the dev release.
See the [issue report here](https://drupal.org/node/2190211).
Thanks for your support.